# My player character is wearing 2 types of armor, how do I decide which calculation is the one to use?

Tags: dnd-5e, armor, armor-class

I've read the other questions about stacking AC which I know can't be done according to the rules, but then the rules also say that you can wear chain shirt under leather, so it contradicts itself there.

My question is about if my player character is wearing it under a leather armor, which the description say it can, which AC should you use? The chain shirt which is closest to the body with an AC of 13 or the leather which would first take the hit with an AC of 11?

How would you handle it?

Comment: How does the answer from the linked questions not cover what you are after? It seems to me as exactly the same question

Comment: Welcome to the stack, take the [tour] when you have a moment. I've closed this as a duplicate of one of the questions you linked, I am failing to see how this is any different. Both your question and the linked duplicate seem to ask the exact same thing: *can I stack armor to get a higher AC?*

Comment: Thomas Markov, sure they are similar, but not the same. Chain mail is not chain shirt and the description says that chain shirt cvan be worn under clothes and leather, so which AC should you use the chain shirt (AC13) or the leather (AC11)?

Comment: I almost voted to reopen this but realised that the linked question isn't actually about specific armor types despite the title, the question itself is "Can one wear multiple types of armor and get an AC stack?" and the answer is pretty clear and covers all types of armor. I did retract my downvote though, because you did put effort into the question. The only thing I can see that might get this opened is if your real question is "my player is wearing 2 types of armor, how do I decide which calculation is the one to use?".

Comment: Oh, then I must I missed that, I have to re-read it and have a second look at it. And thanks for the idea for my queastion :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Pick one.

The rules for [Armor Class](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/step-by-step-characters#ArmorClass) state:

> If you have multiple features that give you different ways to calculate your AC, you choose which one to use.

Comment: Minor clarification: the *player* picks one.

Comment: So, why not just say that you can only use one typ of armor? Everyone most likely understand that wearing a plate armor and leather don't work well, but when the rules it self say that you can wear it under leather, why wouldn't it stack?

If I use a bodyarmor and a plate carrier, they would stack, but I wouldn't be that agile. But wearing two platecarriers on top of each other would not work well at all.  

So a chain shirt and leather should stack, but now I know how to deal with it atleast, even tho I think it's weird :)

Comment: @M.Emmoth We frequently have questions that struggle with how the rules fail to simulate real-world physics, and the tried and true response to those struggles is ["D&D is not a physics simulator"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22physics+simulator%22+%5Bdnd-5e%5D). I think that sentiment applies here as well - D&D is not an armor simulator. If you want armor that provides a higher AC, you just pick armor that provides higher AC, and you accept the tradeoffs that come with that.

Comment: @Tomas Markov, I know that, that is why I wrote that I now know how to handle it, even if I think it's weird ;) The main reason to why I think that is that the rules state that you can wear it under clothes and leather. So they contradicts them self there. But as I said, now I know how to handle it :)

Comment: @M.Emmoth I think the under clothes rule is more aesthetics than mechanics, which for some campaigns is more important than others. It probably could be a clearer rule though if they just said 'here is the list of armour choices, pick ONE'

Comment: @M.Emmoth "Being able to wear two types of armour" and "being able to benefit from two types of armour" are not exactly equivalent, so the rules don't technically contradict themselves; they're just confusingly worded.

Comment: @M.Emmoth You can wear leather over your chainmail, but it's not going to stop any attacks that the chainmail *wouldn't* stop, so you don't get any benefit from it.

Comment: The description says, "...a chain shirt is worn between layers of clothing or leather". Leather, *not* leather armor. Leather is used as barrier so that raw chain links are not rubbing directly against your body.

Comment: @M.Emmoth You may also be missing the mechanical benefits of wearing the armour - worn items cannot be targeted as easily as items that are unattended, your armour may be sundered (leaving you with a second set already worn), you can remove your outer set to sleep (if you assign penalties to sleeping in plate for example). The rules also are written to account for things like monk/barb/mage armour/ with armour which is a lot of stacking. Keep in mind that the DM can rule that stacking armour is better anyway!

Comment: "Features" is not the same as armor worn, that rule refers to Unarmored Defense from Monk and Barbarian not stacking.

Comment: @Slagmoth Items are game features too. If they aren’t, then they aren’t subject to the “game features with the same name rule”, and everything falls apart.